# R: Check existence of url, problems with httr:GET() and url.exists()

Tags: html, r, url, get, httr

I have a list of about 13,000 URLs that I want to extract info from, however, not every URL actually exists. In fact the majority don't. I have just tried passing all 13,000 urls through `html()` but it takes a long time. I am trying to work out how to see if the urls actually exist before parsing them to `html()`. I have tried using `httr` and `GET()` functions, as well as `rcurls` and `url.exists()` functions. For some reason `url.exist()` always returns `FALSE` values even when the URL does exist, and the way I am using `GET()` always returns a success, I think this is because the page is being redirected.

The following URLs represent the type of pages I am parsing, the first does not exist

```
urls <- data.frame('site' = 1:3, 'urls' = c('https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010', 
                            'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=HMM202',
                            'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=SLE339'))

urls$urls <- as.character(urls$urls)
```

For `GET()`, the problem is that the second URL doesn't actually exist but it is redirected and therefore returns a "success".

```
 urls$urlExists <- sapply(1:length(urls[,1]), 
                     function(x) ifelse(http_status(GET(urls[x, 'urls']))[[1]] == "success", 1, 0))
```

For `url.exists()`, I get three FALSE returned even though the first and third urls do exist.

```
 urls$urlExists2 <- sapply(1:length(urls[,1]), function(x) url.exists(urls[x, 'urls']))
```

I checked these two posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130237/rcurl-url-exists-returns-false-when-url-does-exists), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139357/how-to-determine-if-a-url-object-in-r-base-package-returns-404-not-found) but I would prefer not to use a useragent simply because I am not sure how to find mine or whether it would change for different people using this code on other computers. Therefore making the code harder to pick up and use by others. Both posts answers suggest using `GET()` in `httr`. It seems that `GET()` is probably the preferred method but I would need to figure out how to deal with the redirection issue.

Can anyone suggest a good way in R to test the existence of a URL before parsing them to `html()`? I would also be happy for any other suggested work around for this issue.

UPDATE:

After looking into the returned value from `GET()` I figured out a work around, see answers for details.

Comment: You have a conceptual problem here.  With many web servers, if you try to access a page which does not exist, you will still get a page!  What you really want to do is to check for a 404 error coming back.

Comment: Thanks Tim, your comment helped me look into what I was getting back from the `GET()` function. I think I figured out a work around. I have added it to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 20):

With httr, use `url_success()` and redirect following turned off:

```
library(httr)

urls <- c(
  'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010', 
  'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=HMM202',
  'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=SLE339'
)

sapply(urls, url_success, config(followlocation = 0L), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Comment: Just leaving a note since I came across the same issue. With the present version (1.2.1), we use `http_error` instead of `url_success`.

Answer (score 5):

`url_success(x)` is deprecated; please use `!http_error(x)` instead.

So update the solution from hadley.

```
> library(httr)
> 
> urls <- c(  
> 'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010',
> 'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=HMM202',
> 'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=SLE339'
> )
> 
> !sapply(urls, http_error)
```

Answer (score 2):

After a suggestion from @TimBiegeleisen I looked at what was returned from the funtion `GET()`. It seems that if the url exists `GET()` will return this url as a value, but if it is redirected a different url is returned. I just changed the code to look at whether the url returned by `GET()` matched the one I submitted.

```
urls$urlExists <- sapply(1:length(urls[,1]), function(x) ifelse(GET(urls[x, 'urls'])[[1]] == urls[x,'urls'], 1, 0))
```

I would be interested in learning about any better methods that people use for the same thing.