# How to skip nonexistent urls while creating a list of urls in R

Tags: r

I need a hand in generating a list of urls. I try to generate the list with the following lines in R Studio:

```
library(RCurl)
links_list = list()
for(j in 10:46) {
    for(k in 10:99) {
       urls <- c(paste0("https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/tutanaklar/TUTANAK/TBMM/d26/c0", j, "/tbmm260", j, "0", k, ".pdf")) #check 0
    if(url.exists(urls) == TRUE)
    links_list <- c(links_list, urls)
  }
}
```

My aim is to skip the inexistent urls. Before using if, it worked well but the resut was a list of more than 3k urls most of which are inexistent.

I'm working on a PC with Windows but this code doesn't generate a list of urls. The list remains empty when the run is finished. I tried the same in a mac. It worked in a way but the running of the code did not stop.

I appreciate if anyone comes up with an idea!

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest if you kept track of the status of all urls so you could better understand what was happening. Try:

```
j <- 10:46
k <- 10:99
df <- expand.grid(j=j,k=k)
library(dplyr)
h <- getCurlHandle()
df<-df %>%
  mutate(url = paste0("https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/tutanaklar/TUTANAK/TBMM/d26/c0", j, "/tbmm260", j, "0", k, ".pdf"))%>%
  mutate(exists=sapply(url,url.exists,curl=h))
```

In the above code, each row of `df` will have a url and track the return value of `url.exists()`. Then you can simply filter the ones that do using

```
df %>%
  filter(exists)%>%
  pull(url)
```

Do note that I tried this out on a few urls generated and none of them existed so that may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! As you said, df shows that none of the urls exist, but when I tried to open a couple that I'm sure, they worked and the urls opened without any problem. I don't get why all urls are shown false.

Comment: Can you list a valid example that doesn't work but turns up in your browser? Also, there may be an issue with your proxy settings. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130237/rcurl-url-exists-returns-false-when-url-does-exists